# Creating a collapsable navigation when viewed on phone

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a menu that collapses into a button when the page is viewed on a phone. I'm using bootstrap, but for this navigation, I wanted to design the nav differently, so I made my own.

The button does not become visible when the media changes to phone, but the navigation does disappear. How do I make the button appear when the media size changes?

I've tried many things, and this is what I have right now:

HTML:

```
    <div class="pattern col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="banner col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2">
            <img src="img/logo4.png">
        </div>
        <!-- menu -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="mnav-toggle" type="button" id="mnav-toggle">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="mnav col-lg-9 col-med-9 col-sm-4" id="navbar-main">
            <ul class="mnav-list" id="mnav-list">
                <li class="mnav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="mnav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="mnav-item"><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
                <li class="mnav-item"><a href="#">Studios</a></li>
                <li class="mnav-item"><a href="#">Gear</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
    .mnav-list {display: none;}
}

#mnav-toggle
{
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: have you tried inserting #mnav-toggle
{
     display: block;
} into your media query?

Comment: indeed, I did... and still 0 joy I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I can see you need to first add the "display:block" into your query as stated in comment above and secondly the media query should be placed UNDER your baseline css rules like this:

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rJ5Cy/1/)

```
#mnav-toggle
{
    width:20px; height:50px;
    background:red;
     display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px)
{
    .mnav-list {display: none;}
#mnav-toggle{     display: block;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because css rules that are written later gets precedence over the rules written earlier for the same element.